# How to pass dynamic value in scope index angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-model like that:

```
<tr ng-repeat="user in users">

<input type="text" ng-model="code[user.id]"/>
```

When I am using `$scope.code = {0: 'value'};` then it successfully assigned but when I want to pass dynamic value like:

```
var index = 0;
$scope.code = {index: 'value'}
```

then it will not work.

So my Question is, how to pass dynamic value inside the {}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign like this

```
var index = 0; 
$scope.code = {};
$scope.code[index] = 'value';
```

Demo

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
var index = 0; 
$scope.code = {};
$scope.code[index] = 'value';
console.log($scope.code);


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 
</div>
```